# Swift Firebase -How to get all the k/v when using queryOrdered(byChild: ).queryEqual(toValue: )

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
root
  |
  @--reviews
        |
        |
        @--postABC // postId
               |
               |
               @--reviewXYZ // ***I want everything under this reviewUID
               |    |
               |    |--buyerUID: "01010"
               |    |--text: "fast shipping!"
               |    |
               |    @--responseTUV // responseUID
               |         |
               |         |--sellerUID: "212555"
               |         |--text: "we aim to please"
               |     
               @--reviewEFG // this review is from a totally different user I don't want anything from here
```

My database is setup like above. Sometimes I only have the buyer uid so to pull data I use `.queryOrdered(byChild: "buyerUID").queryEqual(toValue: "01010")` and I can locate the buyer from that specific post and it's review.

**How can I get all the other k/v associated with buyer under that node(reviewXYZ) once I locate them?**

```
let reviewsRef = Database.database().reference()?
                   .child("reviews")
                   .child("postABC")
                   .queryOrdered(byChild: "buyerUID")
                   .queryEqual(toValue: "01010")

reviewsRef?.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { [weak self](snapshot) in

    print(snapshot.key) // prints  postABC
    print(snapshot.value) // prints a dictionary with reviewXYZ as the key and everything underneath it as a value

    guard let dict = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] else { return }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`DataSnapshot` class](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Classes/DataSnapshot) has built-in methods to loop over its children.

```
reviewsRef?.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { [weak self](snapshot) in
  for child in snapshot.children {
    let snap = child as! DataSnapshot;
    print(snap.key)
    print(snap.value) 
    print(snap.childSnapshot(forPath: "buyerUID").value)
  }
})
```

Also see other [search results for looping over Firebase child nodes in Swift](https://www.google.com/search?q=firebase+swift+loop+over+children).

Comment: Thanks it worked. For anyone else who uses this in the for loop just cast child as a Datasnapshot. eg- for child in snapshot.children { let x = child as! DataSnapshot; print(x.key); print(x.value); print(x.childSnapshot(forPath: “buyeyUID”).value) }

Comment: Thanks for sharing the correct incantation Lance! I updated my answer to reflect that.

Comment: Since you added the datasnapshot you might want to remove the sentence where you said you it might be missing it. It might confuse some people 